# How to set url parameters in Angular 4

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I've been finding ways to set parameter for this kind of url but I couldn't

http://localhost:9111/v1/companies/{company}/users

where **{Company}**  is the parameter

Anyone have an idea of how to set parameters for this url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)!

```
let company = 'google';

return this.http.get(`http://localhost:9111/v1/companies/${company}/users`);
```

Comment: This needs to use backticks, not single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

**Slight update**

Just jumping to this section will probably be faster: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#link-parameters-array

**original**

Reading around this section of the angular docs should explain in detail what you're trying to do: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-def-with-parameter

In your routing module you define the route in the form ~ `{ path: 'v1/companies/:companyId/users', component: TheComponent }`